# Compatible Hardware to run Hyper-V Manager

Tags: processor, virtual-machines

I am currently running a Hyper-V on Windows Server 2019 using an AMD Ryzen 7 2700 Eight-Core Processor 3.20GHz with 64Gb RAM.

I need a disaster recovery machine that can run the hyper-v machines if this stops working.

Should I look at buying the same processor for the new machine or is the CPU choice not that important as long as they are both AMD Ryzen?

More interested in future-proofing than saving $200 or so. The machine I have had since 2018 and has worked well but it would be good to have more Virtual Processors.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that knowledgeable in this particular subject but as far as I know, the CPU choice shouldn't really matter when running the virtual machine on different systems though there could be some minor issues that you would need to deal it.

Comment: CPU does matter. You need a lot of cores to run VMs

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, Ryzen is a good choice for VMs because you can get a lot of cpu cores for not so expensive. If you don't want any more VMs than you have now, you can buy a ryzen 7 5800x, but if you want more, you can get a ryzen 9 5950x or even threadripper and double the ram. You also need a few ssd's, because VM's need fast and responsive storage.